# How do I get the current post ID within a Gutenberg/Block Editor block?

Tags: block-editor

I would like to access the current post ID from within a block. According to [this documentation page](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core-editor.md), it seems like I should be able to get the post ID with:

```
wp.data.getCurrentPostId();
// or
wp.data.withSelect('core/editor').getCurrentPostId();
// or
wp.editor.getCurrentPostId();
```

but none of those are correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To simply get the value you can call the selector:

```
const post_id = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId();
```

In this case, the post id won't change, so you could assign the value to a constant outside of the component:

```
const { Component } = wp.element;
const { getCurrentPostId } = wp.data.select("core/editor");
const post_id = getCurrentPostId();

// class component
class ExampleClassComp extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{post_id}</div>;
    }
}

// functional component
const ExampleFunctionalComp = () => {
    return <div>{post_id}</div>;
};
```

But if the value changes then it is better to connect the component to the store (for example if using `getGlobalBlockCount()`). So every time the value updates the selector will re-render the component. Here is an example:

Class Component:

```
const { Component } = wp.element;
const { withSelect } = wp.data;

class ExampleClassComp extends Component {
    render() {
        const { post_id, block_count } = this.props;

        return <div>{block_count}</div>;
    }
}

export default withSelect(select => {
    const { getCurrentPostId, getGlobalBlockCount } = select("core/editor");

    return {
        post_id: getCurrentPostId(),
        block_count: getGlobalBlockCount()
    };
})(ExampleClassComp);
```

Functional Component:

```
const { useSelect } = wp.data;

export const ExampleFunctionalComp = () => {
    const post_id = useSelect(select =>
        select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId()
    );

    const block_count = useSelect(select =>
        select("core/editor").getGlobalBlockCount()
    );

    return <div>{block_count}</div>;
};
```

Comment: In my case, `wp.data.select("core/editor")` is undefined.