# Query Post Object in WP Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, id, block-editor

How can I fetch the details of the `$post` object of the very post that I'm working on in WP admin? I've tried `global $post` but I believe that `$post` is not available during editing.

A little context:

I'm digging into Gutenberg by creating my first block and coming up against an issue whereby I don't know how to query properties (type, ID) of the post in the editor. The function which outputs my content (successfully) on the front end uses ACFs `get_field` to fetch a value from an ACF field on that post but fails when I attempt to display a preview of the output in the block editor in the absence of the $post->ID.

Answer (score 0):

The [Beta of ACF 5.8](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-8-introducing-acf-blocks-for-gutenberg/) lets you create Gutenberg blocks with custom fields.
You can preview these block in the editor. Sadly, you have to be an ACF-Pro customer to use the beta.

Otherwise you could try to fetch the custom fields via the REST-API utilizing this plugin: https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/

Refer to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320676/how-do-i-get-the-current-post-id-within-a-gutenberg-block-editor-block) on how get the current Post ID in Gutenberg.

Comment: Thanks, @mtthias. I'm having a play with the Beta now.